# Language parameter in linkedin apply button script

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

I am using AWLI button on our company's page so that the users can apply our jobs with their linkedin profile.

```
<div name="widget-holder">
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://www.linkedin.com/mjobs/awli/awliWidget">
    </script>
    <script type="IN/AwliWidget"  
        data-company-job-code="{UniqueJobCode}" 
        data-integration-context="urn:li:organization:{id}"
        /*  the value inputted here is retrieved from the 
            customer configuration widget (for ATS partners) */
        data-mode="BUTTON_DATA" 
        data-callback-method="onProfileData" 
        data-api-key="{API key}"
        data-allow-sign-in="true">
    </script>
</div>
```

This is the script that we use. As you can see on the page https://www.hays.de/personaldienstleister/cv-upload?prospectIds=D517DF8B-5A2E-4231-9864-5380A632B6C3 (after calling page click on "DE" language button on top right) we have german and english language options, however linkedin button is display always in english. Is there any data attribute or script parameter that we can change the language of button depends of page's language?

Answer (score 0):

Widget language will be automatically inferred based on the language set in the user's browser, and which is supported by LinkedIn. If the user is already cookied by LinkedIn, the widget will display in the language set for their LinkedIn profile.